# What is the unit of time_lock_delta in LND?

Tags: terminology, lightning-network-daemon, channels

LND has a configuration setting called `time_lock_delta` with the description "The required timelock delta for HTLCs forwarded over the channel.". I assume this to refer to some measure of time, but what is the unit of this value?

[image: Screnshot of LND documentation]

None of the four files in the LND repository that contain this string appear to mention the unit either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `time_lock_delta` is the minimum difference in the number of blocks between the CLTV of an incoming HTLC and the forwarded HTLC.

Full details are described in [BOLT2 # CLTV expiry delta](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lightning-rfc/blob/master/02-peer-protocol.md#cltv_expiry_delta-selection).

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that the field `time_lock_delta` in LND corresponds to what [BOLT#7](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lightning-rfc/blob/master/07-routing-gossip.md) refers to as `cltv_expiry_delta`. Which the specification explains to be "the number of blocks it will subtract from an incoming HTLC's `cltv_expiry`".

Hence, the unit would be a count of blocks.